# point of inaccessibility being put on boundary

Tags: r

I have shape x (https://pastebin.com/CPV9wNvJ), the state of MN, that I want to find the POI for

if I run

```
p = polylabelr::poi(x$long, x$lat, precision = 0.01)
```

I get

```
$x
[1] -91.56258

$y
[1] 48.10854

$dist
[1] -0.0000002648542
```

Visualizing this point it puts it right on the boundary:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x` had duplicate rows.

Removing those placed the point where expected.